# Phone number not received in Firebase google login

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-auth-library

I have created following function for login with google account in angular app using Firebase,I am able to login and get user data such as email, name,picture etc but i am not able to get phone number even though i have added phonenumbers scope in provider, i have given public access for phonenumbers in my google account still its not received in response

code:

```
 async googleSignIn() {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read');
    return this.fireauth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(
      async (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.user?.uid));
      },
      (err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Expecting phonenumbes in response object